# (MATLAB) ActiveX -> VBA -> quickest way of filling up / rowwise coloring a MS Word table?

Tags: vba, ms-word, activex

What is the quickest way of creating, filling up and coloring rowwise a MS Word table over ActiveX -> VBA (In my particular case, Im doing it over MATLAB) ?

Right now I'm using it in the following way

```
hdlActiveX = actxserver('Word.Application');
...
hdlActiveX.ActiveDocument.Tables.Add(hdlActiveX.Selection.Range, nbRows, nbCols, 1, 1).Rows.Alignment = 1;
...
% create dataCell{nbRows, nbCols}  containing the table values row- and columnwise
...
nrTable = ... % an integer selecting a table in the MS Word document 
...
for r = 1:nbRows
   for c = 1:nbCols
       % Write data into current cell
      hdlActiveX.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(1).Cell(r,c).Range.Text = dataCell{r, c};

      % setting a different background color rowwise, if a condtion is met
      % this is even bigger performance reducer
      if condition
          for iCol = 1:nbCols
              hdlActiveX.ActiveDocument.Tables.Item(nrTable).Cell(r,iCol).Select;
              hdlActiveX.Selection.Shading.BackgroundPatternColor = color;
          end
      end

   end
end
```

but it takes ages, really, really long to fill up, and especially to color rowwise the MS Word (ActiveX) table ... So how the performance of filling up the table could  be improved ?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I could solve the above question with very simple strategy:

```
1) create a tab-delimitered text file with the table entries (simulate the table)
2) open over activex the text file, and copy its contents
3) create the table rows/cows
4) paste the contents of the whole table.
```

This solved the filling up problem.

The background shading problem could be speed up over pre-defined table formats and rowwise selection and shading (not cellwise).

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking for an answer to this myself.

Making the word app invisble

```
wordApp.Visible = 0;                
wordApp.ScreenUpdating = 0;
```

Reduces my doc creation time from 50 minutes (really.. there are a lot of tables) to 13.